# iOS 11: is it possible not to show notification alert (as banner), but it should be added in notification center?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, swift4, ios11

When the app is in foreground, when 2 or more notifications pushed We must display only one alert and the remaining should be in notification center but should not be alerted as a banner in iOS 11. is it possible?

I've tried the below piece of code.

```
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                       willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        center.getDeliveredNotifications { (notifications) in
            print("number of notifications delivered so far : \(notifications.count)")
            if notifications.count > 0 {

                print(notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as Any)
                // TODO: add to core data
            }
            else {
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
            }
        }
        // Presentation type
        //completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
    }
```

but notification is not appearing in the notification center.

how to know if a notification is being presented in iOS 11.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the application in foreground you will not see the push notifications (neither in notification centre nor in the application). you cannot control how and when the push notifications are presented to the user (and it's better this way).

If you are in the application, the notifications will not remain on the notification centre (all of them are automatically treated like viewed (or read, if you like).

Also, if you are using the simulator it will not work (only on real device).